# C vec3 Struct Implementation

Tags: c

I am attempting to implement a vec3 struct in C. I have it working, but not necessarily how I want. The current code I have is below.

```
typedef struct vec3 {
    float x, y, z;
} vec3;

struct vec3 newvec3(float x, float y, float z) {
    struct vec3 *values = malloc(sizeof(struct vec3));

    values->x = x;
    values->y = y;
    values->z = z;
    return *values;
}
```

In order to declare the struct I have to write.

```
vec3 test = newvec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.4);
```

What I want is.

```
vec3 test = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.4);
```

or something similar. I was wondering if there was a way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: newvec3 make memory leak.  also To be using the C ++.

Comment: yikes, this is very bad. You're getting a memory leak every time you create a new vec3. Typically the way this is done is just declaring the struct and then manually setting its members. `vec3 test; test.x = 0.0; test.y = 1.0; test.z = 0.4`. You can also make use of the fact that structs are contiguous in memory by setting it equal to an array `{x, y, z}`

Comment: You allocate memory, which you then effectively discard: The struct is returned by value and the access to the pointer lost. This is a memory leak.

Comment: I see the memory leak now, and fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
vec3 test = {0.0, 1.0, 0.4};
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get in C to using a type name as a constructor is to use a compound literal:

```
vec3 test = (vec3){ 0.0, 1.0, 0.4 };
```

This of course ditches the function body so you have no real ability to do anything outside set values (it also doesn't allocate dynamic storage; you'll have to do that separately). It gives you a few extra features that are nice to have though (automatically zeroes fields, shorter for complex structs, etc.).

C has multiple namespaces (i.e. multiple ways to interpret the same word), but they're marked out by keywords (like `struct` or `enum`), or they're the main "shared" space. Once you `typedef` a type, you put it in the "shared" space, using up the meaning of that name so it can't also be given to a function. There's no "named func" space or anything like that.

You *could* use a function-like macro to wrap `newvec3`:

```
#define vec3(...) newvec3(__VA_ARGS__)
```

This will only expand `vec3` into `newvec3` when it's in a function-call context, so it would allow the continued use of the name in a type context. But you probably shouldn't do this - it *doesn't* actually add a second meaning to the global namespace, it's just a replacement that sometimes fires and sometimes doesn't (and worse, will fire regardless of scope rules, which violates C semantics for normal type and function names). You have to have two separate names in the actual program space; may as well make it explicit.